# Calculate the offset of the pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I am a c++ novice

After I calculated the pointer of the Player structure, the result was beyond my surprise

```
struct Player
{
    const char* Name = "ab";
    uintptr_t Health = 6;
    uintptr_t Coins  = 3;
} player;



std::cout << &player << std::endl; // 0100C000

uintptr_t* playerBaseAddress = (uintptr_t*)&player;

std::cout << playerBaseAddress << std::endl; // 0100C000
std::cout << (playerBaseAddress + 4) << std::endl; // 0100C010
```

`0100C000+4` How do I get `0100C004` instead of `0100C010`

Can someone explain that, please?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic counts with the size of the pointed type.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the code in the question doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
uintptr_t playerBaseAddress = (uintptr_t)&player;
```

In your version you have a pointer, so when you added `4` to your pointer the result was multiplied by the size of the object being pointed at. Clearly on your platform `uintptr_t` has size 4, so you got `0100C000 + 4*4` which is `0100C010`.

This would also work

```
char* playerBaseAddress = (char*)&player;
```

because here the size of char is 1. so you get `0100C000 + 1*4` which equals `0100C004`.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Use `uintptr_t playerBaseAddress = (uintptr_t)&player;` to get DEC pointer, `std::cout << *(uintptr_t*)(playerBaseAddress + 4) << std::endl; // 6`

Answer (score 1):

In pointer arithmetics, the sizes of the operations are multiplied by the pointed type's size.

This way it's easy to reference data right next to each other in memory.

For example:

```
int* ptr = new int[5];
ptr[3] = 4;
std::cout << *(ptr+3) << endl; // 4
delete[] ptr;
```

You could add four bytes to it by converting it to a pointer type which has the size of one byte, for example `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

`playerBaseAddress` is of type `uintptr_t*` which is a pointer. Presumably `uintptr_t` takes 4 bytes in your environment. Now this piece

```cpp
playerBaseAddress + 4
```

involves the pointer arithmetic: you move the pointer `4*sizeof(uintptr_t)=4*4=16` bytes forward. 16 in hex is 10. Hence your result.

Note that `uintptr_t* playerBaseAddress = (uintptr_t*)&player;` is UB anyway. I assume you meant `uintptr_t playerBaseAddress = (uintptr_t)&player;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the offset into a struct can be done by using [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof), e.g.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct Player {
    const char *name = "ab";
    uintptr_t health = 6;
    uintptr_t coins  = 3;
};

int main()
{
    size_t off = offsetof(Player, health);
    std::cout << "off=" << off << '\n';
}
```

Will show 4 or 8, depending on the architecture and size of the structure's elements.